# Can't add bones to a sphere

Tags: armature, bones

When I clicked on a sphere and then pressed shift + a and looked to add a bone the option doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used bones before on this version of Blender? Or are you in edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

You probably can not add an armature (bone) because you may be in edit mode. If you are in edit mode, then exit, and go to object mode. Then you can add an armature, and use it to rig the sphere. Could you please add an image? That would be very helpful.